# There is so much old stuff on the interweb.... D8 and CiviEntities / Calendar integrations?

Tags: civievent, drupal-8

Just did a D-8.9.2 w/ CiviCRM and am struggling with the some very very old documentation.

Is civi entity still a valid module to help with crossing civi data --> drupal 8?

I tried to composer require it and it failed.

The goal is to show a calendar on the Drupal page that was created in Civi.

Thanks

Comment: git clone civicrm entity directly from its github repo. The maintainers are planning on an alpha release this week. It plays a large role in D8. It will handle e.g. all Views Integration. On my Todo/wish list is to make CiviCRM Entity work with FullCalendar Views module. That would be a whoot for a CiviCRM Activities calendar e.g. But for now Drupal Calendar module (it has an alpha release for D8) works and should allow you to create a Calendar view of CiviCRM Event dates.

Comment: I just saw that module but it failed loading via composer.  I'll try the direct download method.

Comment: I got the civi entity module loaded via git successfully but now  I find that the CiviEvent object does not have a DATE field that is expected in all of the drupal calendar views. I suppose that is something I should take up with that developer.

Comment: Yes file an issue in their GitHub repo. D7DC handles date field fine in Views (for Activities eg) - but with rhe changes in D8 to date fields I’m not suprised if this is an outstanding issue. It’s a big port!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing and configuring [Event Calendar](https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-calendar-extension) extension? It provides UI to configure the calendar and these calendar can be exposed in front end as well. You read the [installation guide](https://github.com/osseed/com.osseed.eventcalendar/blob/master/README.txt) on how to setup a calendar for your site.

Comment: The calendar looks great in civi, but that doesn't help me get it into d8 unless I am missing something.